# Help with backgroud image and exit button

Tags: android, eclipse

How do I add a background image and icon to my app in eclipse?
And an exit button that closes app?

Comment: Read this, then reconsider: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon

Comment: As to the first part: images and icons are basics, and while not difficult, you are in effect asking for a tutorial.  Search on 'Android activity layout background image tutorial eclipse' or such.

Comment: I tried what u suggested what i find is vague and doent work or i cant get it to work. Need specifics

Answer (score 0):

For adding a background on your view simply add in the layout xml file

```
android:background="#000000" or android:background="@drawable/yourdrawable"
```

where **yourdrawable** is your image in the **drawable** folder in your project.

The icon of your app can be changed by replacing the **icon.png** in the drawable folder or  by changing the `android:icon="@drawable/yourdrawable` in the AndroidManifest.xml

For more about icons in Android check [this site.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html)

About adding an exit button in you app you should definitely [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon) first then think about it.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your Direct answer.